# How to identify if the shapes of an image are symmetric or asymmetric using opencv - python?

Tags: python, image, opencv

I'm working on the extraction of image characteristics, in which I'm trying to identify if a certain image is symmetric or not. I am using opecv - python for the development of this work.

The code below is used to identify the center and the diameter of the region of interest. How could you know if this image is symmetrical or not?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import AnchoredText

IMG = '015'
thresh = cv2.imread(IMD+'.png',0)
_, contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,2,1)
print (len(contours))
cnt = contours

for i in range (len(cnt)):
    (x,y),radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(cnt[i])
    center = (int(x),int(y))
    radius = int(radius)
    cv2.circle(thresh,center,radius,(0,255,0),2)
    print ('Circle: ' + str(i) + ' - Center: ' + str(center) + ' - Radius: ' + str(radius))
plt.text(x-21, y+15, '+', fontsize=25, color = 'red')
plt.text(10, -10, 'Centro: '+str(center), fontsize=11, color = 'red')
plt.text(340, -10, 'Diametro: '+str((radius*2)/100)+'mm', fontsize=11,     color = 'red')
plt.Circle((10, -10), 7.2, color='blue')
plt.imshow(thresh, cmap='gray')
#plt.savefig(IMG+'-diam.png')
plt.show()
```

exit:
[image]

In the case, I am wanting to classify if the spot I am analyzing is symmetric or not, the image below, visually it is noted that it is not symmetrical, while the first image of the above plot is symmetrical.

[image]

Comment: Well since you already know the center, I don't see where the problem is. How do _YOU_ see the symmetry? Divide into two _pseudo_ semi circles and compare right? [This link](http://answers.opencv.org/question/877/how-to-match-2-hog-for-object-detection/#882) might be helpful

Comment: Are we talking pixel-perfect symmetry?

Comment: @micycle I updated the question, when speaking in perfect pixel, what would that be? I'm still a layman in this area, I'm learning now.

Comment: Could you explain more on how do you classify the spot as symmetrical or asymmetrical? For me and I bet to anyone else none of the above pictures look symmetrical... They in fact look simmilarly simetrical - if you split the first one vertically two halfs would be "simmilar" as would the second one if you split it by 45 degrees. But none are in fact symmetrical.

Comment: @kavko I'm doing studies on skin patches to idendify whether or not they are carcinogenic. Dermatologists use the ABCD Rule, A - Asymmetry; B - Borders C - Color D - Diameter, and I want to identify just asymmetry. As in this image: https://www.google.com.br/search?q=regras+abcd&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwid6qHXvtTeAhXKk5AKHSoSArsQ_AUIEygB&biw=1366&bih=600#imgrc=Kt0VYg3m80rAEM:

Comment: one method to define object symmetry is the ratio between the two eigenvalues computed from the coordinates within an object. see link for more detail: https://alyssaq.github.io/2015/computing-the-axes-or-orientation-of-a-blob

Answer (score 8):

I assume the variable thresh is a binary image.

In order to find symmetry for a non-uniform object, i suggest we compare the projection of the binary pixels in the X and Y axis.
[image]

Then compare the 2 histogram via histogram comparing method such as correlation, chi-square  or Bhattacharyya distances. ( Example in openCV : https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_comparison/histogram_comparison.html)

```
G_X = cv2.reduce(thresh_square, 0 ,cv2.REDUCE_SUM)
G_Y = cv2.reduce(thresh_square, 1 ,cv2.REDUCE_SUM)

compare_val = cv2.compareHist(G_X ,G_Y ,cv2.HISTCMP_CORREL)
```

where thresh_square is a squared ROI centered at your binary blob. You need to have equal bins for G_X and G_Y to make meaningful comparison.

A higher correlation value should correspond to a symmetric object while a lower correlation value will corresponds to an asymmetrical object.

Run this code to a few of the symmetric and asymmetric examples and check the compare_val value. You should be able to find a threshold to separate the two.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I would go about this problem:

1. Measure the distance from the center for each radii
2. Split the measurements into two groups (0 to 180, 180 to 360)
3. Get the average of the two groups and compare to see if they are equal within a margin of error.
4. Rotate the splitting of the groups by 1 degree and try again until you get to 179 degrees
5. check if any splitting returned are equal within the margin.

You may have to tweak the equality margin a while to find a range that is acceptably accurate.

Also, you may have to quorum check the rotations to see if x rotations are equal within margin then it is symmetrical.

you may also need to divide it into quadrants instead of half pending how many axis you want to check symmetry for.